# Solving $\max z = (3x_1 - x_2)$ linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am trying to solve this linear programming exercise using the Simplex method.

First of all, I detail every step, so it is pretty long, but the real question (the part where I'm stuck at) is at the bottom - the procedure is here just in case.

---

$$\max z = \ (3x_1-x_2)$$
$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2 \le 3\\
2x_1\le x_2\\
x_1+x_2\ge 12\\
x_2 \le 10\\
x_1,x_2 \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

On the second row, I'll just move the $x_2$ to the left:
$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2 \le 3\\
\color{red}{2x_1 - x_2 \le 0}\\
x_1+x_2\ge 12\\
x_2 \le 10\\
x_1,x_2 \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

Now, time to transform all inequalities to equations. This is done by adding four variables, $x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$:
$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2 + x_3 = 3\\
2x_1 - x_2 + x_4 = 0\\
x_1+x_2-x_5 = 12\\
x_2 + x _6 = 10
\end{cases}$$

In matrix form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & \color{red}0 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & \color{red}0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{-1} & 0 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}0 & 1 & 10 \\
-3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}0 & 0 & -z
\end{bmatrix}$$

However, the fifth column (the one for $-x_5$) is not canonical, because its variable's coefficient is $-1$. Thus we must add an artificial variable, $x_7$ to the system, creating a canonical column:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}0 & 3 \\
2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \color{blue}1 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \color{blue}0 & 10 \\
-3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}0 & -z
\end{bmatrix}$$

We have expanded our linear program, and we must solve new problem, which is

$$\min w = x_7$$

Hence, we add a new row to the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
-3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -z\\
\color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}1 & \color{blue}w
\end{bmatrix}$$

To solve this expanded problem, we need it to be in canonical form. However, the seventh column has two $1$s. We can remove the last $1$ by performing

$$-r_3 + r_6$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
-3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -z\\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & w-12
\end{bmatrix}$$

The expanded program is now in canonical form, so we can work it out with the Simplex algorithm. The pivot is the $2$ from the first column, because $0/2 = 0$.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\color{red}2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
-3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -z\\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & w-12
\end{bmatrix}$$

Convert the pivot to a $1$:

$$\frac{1}{2}r_2$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & -1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
-3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -z\\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & w-12
\end{bmatrix}$$

And then perform

$$-r_2+r_1 , -r_2+r_3 , 3r_2+r_5 , r_2+r_6$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1/2 & 1 & -1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & -1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \color{red}{3/2} & 0 & -1/2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
0 & -1/2 & 0 & -3/2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -z+36\\
0 & -3/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & w-12
\end{bmatrix}$$

The next pivot is $3/2$, because $12 / 3 / 2 = 2$ which is lower than $10/1 = 10$.

We convert the pivot to a $1$:

$$\frac{2}{3}r_3$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1/2 & 1 & -1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & -1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \color{red}1 & 0 & -1/3 & -2/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 8 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
0 & -1/2 & 0 & -3/2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -z+36\\
0 & -3/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & w-12
\end{bmatrix}$$

And perform

$$\frac{1}{2}r_3+r_1 , \frac{1}{2}r_3+r_2 , -r_3+r_4, \frac{1}{2}r_3 + r_5, \frac{3}{2}r_3+r_6$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & -2/3 & -1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 7 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1/3 & -2/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 10 & -2/3 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -5/3 & -10/3 & 0 & 10/3 & -z + 40 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & w
\end{bmatrix}$$

We have solved the expanded linear program. I can now remove the last row:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & -2/3 & -1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 7 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1/3 & -2/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 10 & -2/3 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -5/3 & -10/3 & 0 & 10/3 & -z + 40
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since the column that corresponds to the artificial variable $x_7$ is not basic, we can remove it too:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & -2/3 & -1/3 & 0 & 7 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1/3 & -2/3 & 0 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 10 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -5/3 & -10/3 & 0 & -z + 40
\end{bmatrix}$$

**PROBLEM**

Ok, I have been working in an analogous manner as an example I saw before. In that example, when the removed the artificial column, they ended up with a canonical program, so they were able to execute the Simplex on it. But this case is **different**:

As you can see, this program **still isn't canonical**. I have three canonical vectors, but I need four.

So...

- Did I do something wrong in my procedure?
- Do I *actually need* four canonical columns? As far as I recall, the program only uses $x_1$ and $x_2$ - can't I simply remove all other columns?
- Or is it as simple as performing $\frac{1}{10}r_4$? (not sure if I am allowed)